# Can i create a cross platform Xamarin Forms application in F#?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, f#

As the title says, is this currently an option? As can be seen in the screenshot, I don't see an option for creating a crossplatform project in Visual Studio. Is there a way around this i.e. is the cross-platform option just there for conveniently setting up the project structure? If so, how should I do this?

[image: New Project Choices]

Comment: Visual Studio for Windows dropped the F# Cross-platform solution/project when they removed the PCL-based Xamarin.Forms solution (not sure of the reasoning as Netstd2.0 works fine w/ f#). Check out the **Xamarin.Forms Book** samples on Github as there are complete solution/projects examples using F# there that you can model your own after. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/fsharp/samples/

Comment: Another sample F# mixed with C#. The blog post and code were published a few days ago so I assume they shoud run with recent framework versions and tools out of the box: [Building An F# Redux Store For C# Xamarin Apps](https://thomasbandt.com/fsharp-redux-store-for-xamarin-apps)

Comment: And there's even a full sample of the MvvmNano Demo App, written fully in F#: https://github.com/ixmrm01/MvvmNanoDemo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references others have posted are good, except that not all those projects are .Net Standard 2.0, so if you use them, you will need to upgrade later. But even without a current template, creating a Xamarin Forms F# solution is not hard:

1. Create a new .Net Standard C# Xamarin.Forms project. Delete the .Net Standard C# library, leaving the platform-specific parts.
2. Add a .Net Standard 2.0 F# library, install the Xamarin.Forms package, and connect the platform projects to it.
3. Define an App class in this library:

   ```
   type SomeNamespace.App() =
       inherit Xamarin.Forms.Application()
       do base.MainPage <- ...
   ```
4. Refer to this in the (C#) platform projects: `LoadApplication(new SomeNamespace.App());`

Comment: Thanks! Does the crossplatform project need a reference to the ios and android projects, or the other way around?

Comment: No it's the other way around.